# nginx rewrite rule (with variable data)

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a website https://www.my-domain.com. In some cases, people access to a specific resource of it, https://www.my-domain.com/**%26**/something/variableData
What I want to achieve is to redirect those specific cases to https://www.my-domain.com/**&**/something/variableData

I know that I need a specific location block to handle requests to "%26", and a rewrite rule to point them to "&", but keeping also the /variableData part passed as an argument (variableData is an id)

```
location /%26/something/ {
   rewrite ^(/%26/something/*)$ /&/something/$1;
   proxy_pass https://myInternalServerIP
}
```

This is not working. I'm missing something but I don't know what. Also I am unsure of how nginx handles encoded characters, as %26. If it treats them as literal of it tries to decode.
Something else is that I don't know if I need a specific location block for this rewrite or I can add it in / . My current / location block is as follows:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass https://myInternalServerIP
    }
```

Examples of the url are:

- https://www.my-domain.com/%26/something/afgrtqwmmoi6
- https://www.my-domain.com/%26/something/876hjsd542hl

And I want them to be translated to:

- https://www.my-domain.com/&/something/afgrtqwmmoi6
- https://www.my-domain.com/&/something/876hjsd542hl

Hope someone can spot the error

Comment: `%26` is a URL encoded `&`. The Nginx `location` statement should only see the decoded URI. The `%26` has been converted to `&` at that point. Also, your regex is missing a `.` and should finish with `/.*)$`

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith. I did the change that you mention and the line with the rewrite became:
rewrite ^(/%26/something/.*)$ /&/something/$1;
but still unable to correctly rewrite it. Regarding your comment that nginx should only see the decoded &, if that is the case, rewrite rule shouldn't be needed. But if I try to access to https://www.my-domain.com/%23/something/876hjsd542hl y get a 404 error. Also in nginx access logs y see the url with %23, not the decoded "&"